# Extraneous ' in diagram using package xy[barr,pdf]

Tags: diagrams, diagxy

I get an extraneous ' in node up0 (U'^0) with the following

```
\documentclass{tac}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[barr,pdf]{xy}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}

% The TAC hyperref setup should be reloaded after other packages

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup {
   allcolors=[rgb]{0.1,0.1,0.4},
   colorlinks,
   pdfinfo={
      Author={Shmuel (Seymour J.) Metz},
      Keywords={fibre bundles;manifolds},
      Subject={Topology},
      Title={A Proposed Unification of Manifolds and Fibre Bundles}
   }
}

  % Select font for function and sequences of function
  \newcommand \funcname [1] {\mathit{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure} [hbt]
\[ \bfig
\node x(0,500)[x]
\node u0l(-1000,0)[U_0]
\node up0(0,0)[U'_0]
\node u0r(1000,0)[U_0]
\node u1(-1000,-500)[U_1]
\node up1(-500,-500)[U'_1]
\node vp1(500,-500)[V'_1]'
\node v1(1000,-500)[V_1]
\node d1(-1000,-1000)[\vdots]
\node d2(-500,-1000)[\vdots]
\node d3(500,-1000)[\vdots]
\node d4(1000,-1000)[\vdots]
\node um(-1000,-1500)[U_m]
\node upm(-500,-1500)[U'_m]
\node vpn(500,-1500)[V'_n]
\node vn(1000,-1500)[V_n]
\arrow |l|/^{ (}->/[x`up0;i]
\arrow |b|/^{ (}->/[up0`u0l;i]
\arrow |a|[up0`up1;\funcname{f}_0]
\arrow |a|[up0`vp1;\funcname{f}'_0]
\arrow |b|/^{ (}->/[up0`u0r;i]
\arrow |r|[u0l`u1;\funcname{f}_0]
\arrow |l|[u0r`v1;\funcname{f}'_0]
\arrow |r|[u1`d1;\funcname{f}_1]
\arrow |t|/^{ (}->/[up1`u1;i]
\arrow |l|[up1`d2;\funcname{f}_1]
\arrow |t|/^{ (}->/[vp1`v1;i]
\arrow |r|[vp1`d3;\funcname{f}'_1]
\arrow |l|[v1`d4;\funcname{f}'_1]
\arrow |r|[d1`um;\funcname{f}_{m-1}]
\arrow |r|/^{ (}->/[d2`d1;i]
\arrow |l|[d2`upm;\funcname{f}_{m-1}]
\arrow |r|/^{ (}->/[d3`d4;i]
\arrow |r|[d3`vpn;\funcname{f}'_{n-1}]
\arrow |l|[d4`vn;\funcname{f}'_{n-1}]
\arrow |r|/^{ (}->/[upm`um;i]
\arrow |a|//[upm`vpn;\sim]
\arrow |b|/ >.>>/[upm`vpn;\funcname{f}'']
\arrow |t|/^{ (}->/[vpn`vn;i]
\efig \]
\caption{Local nearly commutative diagram}
\label{fig:NCDl}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the `barr` option you show for `xy`? I don't find it documented in the XY-pic User's Guide or located anywhere in xypic.sty or xy.sty. (Does it load Michael Barr's `diagxy`?)

Comment: From http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/doc/xyrefer.pdf: 33 Barr’s diagram feature
Vers. 2011-06-18 by Michael Barr hbarr@math.mcgill.cai
Load as: \xyoption{barr}
This option contains support for a special compact
syntax for categorical diagrams. It is documented in
the included separate document barrdoc.pdf, which
also has a comparison with using the matrix feature.

Comment: But where is that option executed in either `xy.sty` or `xy.tex`? I don't find any occurrence of `barr` in either.

Comment: I don't know why it's not in the others, but it's certainly in /xyrefer.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

There is a stray apostroph after this line:

```
   \node vp1(500,-500)[V'_1]' %<---- here
```

Comment: What tipped you off that the problem wasn't in the up0 node or anything to the left of it? Do you have any hints for diagnosing such problems in the future? Thanks.